# Vue - Trigger event only if you press the key twice in a row

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm implementing a special field in my application, when the user input the `@ (shift + 50)` character, a window will pop up so the user can access predefined variables...

```
<textarea @keyup.shift.50="showWindow"></textarea>
```

My question is: I do not want the window to appear when the user presses the key only once, I want the window to appear when he presses the keys a twice.

Is it possible?

Comment: _"he presses the keys a twice"_ do you mean like a double-click, or just trigger on a second click? (ie. does the time delta between the clicks matter?)

Comment: @Daniel Yes, double-click, but in my case I just capture the keyup event... The time matter... I think the timing should be similar to a forlder click in a computer, if you just click on it, you select it, if you click fast enough it will open...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**============NEW============================================**

Edit: modified and cleaned up the code for you - this code is more efficient and does not contain any 'bugs' (there are some flaws in the other code)..

Explanation: I basically collect all 'shift.50' key presses and compare their delta - then overwrite - this means if you press 'shift.50' then dont press it again til 5 minutes later (would be the 2nd click in the old code) you would have to essentially click it 3 times to fire the 'do the needful' event..

https://jsfiddle.net/yL57kbhf/

```
var myapp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    delta: 1000, // in ms
    keyPress: null,
  },
  methods: {
    keyPressed(key) {
      if(this.keyPress !== null){ 
        let d = key.timeStamp - this.keyPress.timeStamp;
        if(this.delta > d){
            alert('do something here!')
        }
      }
      this.keyPress = key;
    },
  }
})
```

.

.

**=============OLD============================================**

Explanation: In the following code I keep track of how many times you click the 'shift.50' button using the data property 'pressCount'. On the first press I store the click event in 'keyPress' in an effort to compare the delta (which is a property you can set under 'delta') with the second key press. If there are 2 consecutive key presses within N (where N=delta) then you can "do the needful"..

https://jsfiddle.net/c0tk6pbx/

```
var myapp = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: {
    delta: 1000, // in ms
    pressCount: 0,
    firstPress: null,
  },
  methods: {
    keyPressed(key) {
        this.pressCount++;
        if(this.pressCount === 1){
        this.firstPress = key;
      } 
      if(this.pressCount === 2){
        let d = key.timeStamp - this.firstPress.timeStamp
        if(this.delta > d){         
            alert("do something here");
        }
        this.pressCount = 0;
      }
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but it might help if you explained the relevant parts of the code you added in the answer, instead of just providing a link. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer "Provide context for links"